# Scramble a list of elements in Prolog using a particular predicate?

Tags: prolog

so I have the following predicate which inserts an item at random into a list to give multiple solutions:

```
insert(X,Y,Z):- append(A,B,X),append(A,[Y|B],Z).
```

I want to write another predicate which scrambles the elements in a list and returns multiple solutions. I'm aware there's a library function called random_permutation or something but I would like to know how to write it based off of my own predicate?

I tried the following but it seems hopelessly wrong:

```
permute([],[]).
permute(X,Y):-insert(X,_,Z),permute(Z,Y).
```

So using this predicate I could type permute([1,2,3],X). and get back as results [1,3,2],[2,3,1], etc.... for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
permute([],[]).
permute([X|Xs],Y) :- permute(Xs,P), insert(P,X,Y).
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much!